# Add a TextBox within a text editor control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to add controls within a richtextbox control.

i want to give control to user to insert text in the textbox placed in richtextbox. user may edit text in richtextbox or may insert text in textbox

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use "Telerik" and create your control within third party control.

Comment: This does not answer the question posted.